# Applying a property to each element in several arrays, then returning a flat map with one array

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I have a collection that looks like this

```
[
  {
    count: 123,
    description: 'some description',
    articles: [
     {...}
    ]
  },
  {
    count: 234,
    description: 'some description',
    articles: [
      {...}
    ]
  }
]
```

Each object in the collection has a collection of articles. **What I need** is to apply the `description` to each article object in the respective collection in each element of the primary collection. I also want to end up with a flat array containing only articles. Clearly I'm using `mergeMap` incorrectly, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have tried this

```
json$.pipe(
    // Filter out empty arrays
    filter(section => section.count > 0),
    // Apply the descriptions 
    map(section => section.articles.map(a => (Object.assign(a, section.sectionName)))),
    mergeMap(x => x.articles)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But the articles do not have the `description` property in them, and it's not a flat array of articles. I've tried a few things but I'm unsure how to proceed

Comment: What do you mean by "apply the description to each article object"?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to apply the `description` property to each `article` object in the `articles` array. Like `articles.map(a => ({...a, description})`. Yoshi has supplied a solution that takes of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to `concatMap` the outer observable, after adjusting each article.

```js
const { Observable } = Rx;
const { map, concatMap, filter } = Rx.operators;

const json$ = Observable.from([
  {
    count: 123,
    description: 'some description 123',
    articles: [
      {id: 1},
      {id: 2},
    ]
  },
  {
    count: 234,
    description: 'some description 234',
    articles: [
      {id: 3},
      {id: 4},
    ]
  }
]);

const withDescription$ = json$.pipe(
  filter(({count}) => count > 0),
  concatMap(
    ({articles, description}) => Observable.from(articles).map(a => ({...a, description}))
  )
);

withDescription$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@^5/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you don't need any special behavior on the inner observable, you could simplify to:

```
const withDescription$ = json$.pipe(
  filter(({count}) => count > 0),
  concatMap(
    ({articles, description}) => articles.map(a => ({...a, description}))
  ),
);
```